# how can I linearize a constraint of the form $\sum (\min(x(i),y(i)))$ for a linear optimisation problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints, linearization

I have an linear optimization problem, and I'd like to impose a constraint of the following form:

$∑_{i=0}^N \min⁡(x_i,y_i)≥C$ where $x_i,y_i$ are rational numbers greater or equal to 0. How can I linearize it ?

*Edit*

Optimization objective :

$ \max \text{PortfolioSpread}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N) = (∑_{i=0}^Nx_is_i)/\text{budget}$

s.t.

1. $∑_{i=0}^N x_i = \text{budget}$  (+ other constraints)
2. $∑_{i=0}^N \min⁡(x_i,y_i)≥C$

where decision variables $x_i$ represent market values, $y_i$ represent current holdings expressed in market values while $C$ is the constraint value.

I've used lpsolve to run this optimization exercise without the second constraint, and now I'd like to add the second constraint as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`min` is a concave function. Therefore the left-hand side of the constraint is concave as is, making the constraint convex as is. Therefore it can be linearized without use of binary or integer variables.

Specifically, for each $i$, declare a new continuous optimization (decision) variable $z_i$ (it might be the case that you wish to declare $z$ as a vector consisting of all the $Z_i$). Replace the constraint with $∑_{i=0}^N z_i≥C$ and add the constraints $z_i \le x_i, z_i \le y_i$

It might appear these constraints enforce $z_i \le \text{min}(x_i,y_i)$ rather than $z_i = \text{min}(x_i,y_i)$. But the optimization will drive this to $z_i = \text{min}(x_i,y_i)$ at the optimum, because the optimizer will want to make the constraint as weak as the formulation allows, to give it the most optimization capability.

Many (linear) optimization solvers and optimization modeling languages allow use of `min`, and will handle this reformulation automatically (under the hood).

I am adding CVX (under MATLAB) code showing how to do this in that tool

```
cvx_begin
variables x(N+1) z(N+1)
% omitting code except for constraint of interest
z <= x
z <= y
sum(z) >= C
cvx_end
```

However, this can be done even more simply in CVX, using its ability to allow convex use of min (similarly in CVXR and CVXPY).

```
cvx_begin
variable x(N+1)
% omitting code except for constraint of interest
sum(min(x,y,[],2)) >= C % x and y are column vectors, and min is taken across each row
cvx_end
```

Comment: in my case $x_i$ are decision variables and $y_i$ are constants. I am not sure I understand how to introduce a new variable in my context. Could you expand on that or give me an example please? Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that $z_i$ are optimization (decision) variables. You introduce a new (optimization) decision variable in the same way you declare other optimization variables, such as the $x_i$.  This formulation works whether or not both $x_i$ and $y_i$ are optimization variables.

Comment: If you are using R"s lpsolve , I believe you need to define all variables as a single vector. So that means to introduce the $z_i$, you need to make that vector double the length, Then the constraints involving $z_i$ need to use the corresponding indices.  You might find it simpler to use an optimization modeling language such as CVXR (for R), which lets you define as many optimization variables as you want. That makes it simpler and less error-prone to enter the problem. If using Python, the corresponding tool is CVXPY and in MATLAB it is CVX.

Comment: Brilliant, I've managed to implement your solution in lpsolve by making the vector double in length as you suggested and changing the matrices used for other constraints.